# How do I mass remove certain characters from directory/file names

Tags: command-line, files, fedora, rename

What's a command I could use to do this on fedora 29
I need to remove [,], and -. If possible just remove the characters. Otherwise I'm good with replacing them as '_'
I have 2,400+ files and directories with sub directories named similar to:

```
TWENTY_ONE_PILOTS_-_DISCOGRAPHY_(2009-15)_CHANNEL_NEO]
```

I need it to be easy to make a directory out of. For example:

```
TWENTY_ONE_PILOTS_DISCOGRAPHY_2009_15_CHANNEL_NEO
```

I've tried:

```
find . -depth -name '*]*' -execdir bash -c 'for i; do mv "$i" "${i

│// /_}"; done' _ {} +
```

And

```
for x in *]*; do mv -- "$x" "${x//[/}"; done
```

Andd

```
rename 's/\(|\[|\]|\)//g' *
```

Comment: Should all `_-_` be converted to just `_`?

Comment: If possible. Or any double __ to single _ I'm just trying to get the files to be human and machine readable.

Comment: In `for x in *]*; do mv -- "$x" "${x//[/}"; done` try escaping the replaced right bracket: `for x in *]*; do mv -- "$x" "${x//\[/}"; done`

Comment: Better yet, use sed to generate the new names and echo them to verify that it works.  Then add the `mv` command.

Comment: I get mv: cannot move 'Rag’n’Bone_Man_Human_2017]_320' to a subdirectory of itself, 'Rag’n’Bone_Man_Human_2017]_320/Rag’n’Bone_Man_Human_2017]_320'
When using the above codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use : `find . -exec sh -c './correct.sh {}' \;` !

With correct.sh in the same directory as you launch the above command :

> #!/bin/bash
>
> mv "$1" $(echo "$1" | sed 's/_-_/_/g');

(Don't forget to `chmod +x correct.sh` !)

It is not a very elegant solution but it work though. Everything is self explanatory except maybe the `-exec` which is an option of `find` that will execute for each name of the files, the process mentionned (here `sh -c '...'`) and replace {} by the file's name ! See [find man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for more informations.

If you want to rename only the file directory, insert `-type d` as an option of find. And of course, you can modify as much as you like the sed to replace what you want.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
$ autoload zmv
$ zmv -n '(**/)(*)' '$1${${${2//[^.[:alnum:]]##/_}##_#}%%_#}'
mv -- TWENTY_ONE_PILOTS_-_DISCOGRAPHY_\(2009-15\)_CHANNEL_NEO\] TWENTY_ONE_PILOTS_DISCOGRAPHY_2009_15_CHANNEL_NEO
```

Turns all sequences of characters other than alnums and `.` to `_`, and removes the leading and trailing `_`s afterwards, in all files and directories, recursively.

`-n` is for *dry run*, remove it when happy.

If you only want to rename files of type *directory*, change the `(**/)(*)` to `(**/)(*)(#q/)`